# Android RTSP coding problem

Tags: android, audio-streaming, rtsp

I have Googled my butt off trying to find where if there is a surefire way to make rtsp work.  I have a radio station that I listen to that streams via rtsp.  Of course by default Android doesn't want to play it.  If I pop the URL into yourmuze.fm and create a station there it lets me stream it to my phone.  After checking how it works I come to find that it streams to the phone via rtsp!  So obviously there is something amiss.  What makes one stream work and one not?   This is the stream I am attempting :  rtsp://wms2.christiannetcast.com/yes-fm

It is an audio stream so I would be thrilled with most peoples problem of "it only does audio and not video."  When yourmuze.fm streams, DDMS states it brings up MovieView to play the audio if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetApex, using live555's openRTSP tool to access the wms2.christiannetcast.com/yes-fm link, they are using a WMS server and do not support RTSP with RTP transport.  I don't believe that Android supports Windows interleaved transport method which might work.  I'd search for streaming windows audio streams to Android and you may find something that works.

Comment: Very good info!  That is just what I was looking to hear (an answer to why).  I will see what other choices I have then.  Thanks!